# What do you call someone that doesn't want to use something unless they understand it?

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations

By someone, I mean myself.

I acknowledge the fact that I use things anyways, but it bothers me so much to the point that the thought has become frustrating. I know I'll have to get used to it at some point in time, as I can't delve in to the world of atoms or quarks and all those subatomic structures any time soon.

I tried looking it up online, but the word doesn't seem to exist, that or I just don't know the term.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [clarify your specific problem](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The title should be self explanatory, but here's the question, again. **It's someone that doesn't want to use something unless they know what makes it work, what it's made of, it's limits, etc.** Or maybe I've just discovered a new feeling? I'm not sure.

Comment: Sound somewhat like a *control freak* ?

Comment: So in that case, the person won't eat, drink or breath, unless they're sure what's the food, drink or air made of?

Comment: Unless it be *over-cautious* I'm sure there's no such word, nor anything like it, even though there's no faint chance of ever proving that.

I don't think this is what you were looking for and your explanation seems to make it fairly clear such a person would be described as obsessive-compulsive; possibly OC squared.

Comment: -    I wouldn't say it's a control freak, as I'd just want to know a lot of information; not by force nor manipulation, rather, through investigation.          -    The person knows that they'd have to eat, drink or breath eventually, but they would like to understand everything about it from a scientific point of view (composition, anatomy, physics, every other branch, etc).                   -    I wouldn't mark it down as a fear or an overwhelming thought. It's more out of curiosity than compulsiveness.

Comment: I found a phrase that might aid with the search. It's from The Essence of Alan Watts Vol. 4: **"What I am saying then is just because you don’t know how you manage to be conscious, how you manage to grow and shape your body, doesn’t mean that you’re not doing it. Equally, if you don’t know how the universe shines the stars, constellates the constellations, or galactifies the galaxies – you don’t know but that doesn’t mean that you aren’t doing it just the same way as you are breathing without knowing how you breathe."**

Comment: Duh!!  He's a GEEK!

Comment: Try "engineer".

Answer (score 1):

The only word which comes to mind is `Cartesian`.
It's not 100% what you are looking for, but maybe close enough?

Comment: The definition I'm seeing is "relating to Descartes and his ideas". If you had another definition in mind, be sure to include it in your post.

Comment: Cartesian anxiety seems to fit the description, but it's not a fear for the unknown. I feel that it's more out of curiosity, but curious isn't the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the psychological context.

Say we have a person who is willing to use something they don't fully understand, but doing so generates low-level anxiety.  When their analyst drills down, they discover the person has a fear of the unknown.  They fear that their lack of knowledge will cause "something really bad" to happen.

You might call that person mildly **xenophobic.**  If the person was actually afraid of failing, then they might be called **atychiphobic**.

*(Ironically you and I are in the same boat.  I hesitate to assign a word to your condition unless I understand it better.)*

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a phobia of sorts, rather it's a need to learn; an inquisitive set of thoughts. I do agree that I don't want "something really bad" to happen, thus I would need to understand how things work. I don't think it's a phobia though.

Answer (score 0):

In American English [**mindful**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mindful) means **giving attention (to)**

> **Mindful** of the poor road conditions, she drove slowly.

*Mindful* people think about things like that, whereas others might not give it a second thought. To be [mindful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mindful) just means you're

> Conscious or aware of something.

And you have to be conscious of things, to try to understand them. The reason you wouldn't feel comfortable using things you don't understand, is because you are *mindful* of the fact that you don't understand them, and that alone is enough to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you described that you strive for knowledge "more out of curiosity than compulsiveness", which makes me think that you possess a very [**inquisitive**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquisitive) mind:

> Given to inquiry or research; eager for knowledge; curious.

Another related concept dealing with your reluctance to accept things you don't understand might be [**skepticism**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/skepticism):

> A doubting or questioning attitude or state of mind; dubiety.

Combining the two parts together, one may end up with [**"skeptically inquisitive"**](https://www.google.ru/search?q="skeptically+inquisitive") which appears to be amply used in modern English literature.

On a personal note, I can relate to your light anxiety when dealing with things you don't know all ins and outs of and do feel that this expression sounds way more pretentious than it should. Even though realistically speaking, one needs a degree or two to know how something as deceivingly simple as the bicycle [really works](http://ruina.mae.cornell.edu/research/topics/bicycle_mechanics/stablebicycle/StableBicyclev34Revised.pdf) even on the macro level.